# Find the length of $\{z \in \mathbb C: |z-1|+|z+1|=4\}$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find the length of $\{z \in \mathbb C: |z-1|+|z+1|=4\}$.

If we could write $z=x+iy$, then this is an ellipse of the form
$$\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{3}=1$$
So $x=2\cos t, y=\sqrt{3}\sin t$, so the path is
$$\gamma(t)=2\cos t+i\sqrt{3}\sin t, t \in [0, 2\pi]$$
Thus, the primeter of the ellipse is
$$\begin{aligned}
\int^{2\pi}_0|\gamma'(t)|dt & =\int^{2\pi}_0|-2\sin t +i\sqrt{3}\cos t|dt\\
& =\int^{2\pi}_0 \sqrt{4\sin^2t+3\cos^2t}dt\\
& =\int^{2\pi}_0\sqrt{3+\sin^2t}dt
\end{aligned}$$
Any help with how to go any further? Thanks~

Comment: I think this has to be continued using numerical integration.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433094/how-to-determine-the-arc-length-of-ellipse

Comment: This integral is non-elementary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336184/circumference-of-an-ellipse/2336274#2336274) I give the solution for the arc length of an ellipse in the complex plane, e.g.,

$$
z=a\cos t+ib\sin t,\quad t\in[0,2\pi]\\
s=\int |\dot z|~dt
$$

The solution can be expressed in terms of the comple elliptic integral of the second kind or the Gauss hypergeometric function  as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
s
&=\int_0^{2\pi}b\sqrt{A\sin^2\theta+1}~d\theta,\quad A=\left(\frac{a^2-b^2}{b^2}\right)\\
\\
&=4b\text{E}(-A)=4b\frac{\pi}{2}~ _2\text{F}_1\left(-\frac 12,\frac 12;1;-A \right)
\end{align}
$$

For $a=2$ and $b=\sqrt{3}$, we find that $s\approx11.7397$.